# Google Groups: Disable Group through Python API

Tags: python, google-provisioning-api

I am using the Python Gdata API to manage Google Groups for my organization and am interested in using the "Disable Group" feature that is now available in the "New" Google Groups.  Is this feature supported in the API?

I am using the methods listed on this page:
http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pydocs/gdata.apps.groups.service.html

I appreciate any help given.

Comment: I think the 'disable' feature could be emulated by using the Group Settings API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/groups-settings/

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

I don't think it is possible via Group Setting API.

The description for disabling a group is below:

"Once disabled all new posts to the group will be rejected. Old messages will be browseable and searchable online by anyone that has permission to view the group's content. If this setting is reverted, 'Who can post messages' will automatically be set to 'Managers only' in the 'Basic permissions' section."

I try to use the group setting API and change the setting from all in domain can post to just all manager can post to limit the posting of the group.

"whoCanPostMessage": "ALL_IN_DOMAIN_CAN_POST" -> ALL_MANAGERS_CAN_POST

Note if you take a look at the basic permission for a disabled group, it unchecked all the users who are allowed to post.  However, the group setting APi only limit to you change to ALL manager can post.

So it didn't really disable a group...

Comment: I believe you can set use the NONE_CAN_POST settings with whoCanPostMessage.  This will set the group to archive only.

Comment: Correction: when setting NONE_CAN_POST also set archiveOnly to True.